# Unable to change permission for @everyone?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to change a permission of the role everyone, but when I go back to see the role permissions I see that nothing changed. 
Here there is the code:

```
role = get(ctx.guild.roles, "@everyone")
await role.edit(stream=False)
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Role.edit) it states that you must pass a permission object through as `permissions` to do this.

Here is an example of how to change a role's permissions:

```py
# I suggest you use guild.get_role(role_id) if it's not always the default role, and this built in method if it is.
role = guild.default_role
await role.edit(permissions=discord.permissions(stream=False))
```